# How to merge two rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table similar to this one:

```
Date     | Cond   | Time
---------+--------+------
18/03/19 |   1    | 13:07
18/03/19 |   0    | 16:07
```

I want to have a selection that would produce thing similar to that using join or union or any sort of condition

```
 Date     | Time1 | Time2
----------+-------+------
 18/03/19 | 13:07 | 16:07
```

Best regards

Comment: Add some more rows with sample table data, and adjust the result if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select date, max(case when cond = 1 then time end) as time_1,
       max(case when cond = 0 then time end) as time_0
from t
group by date
order by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate function

```
select date,min(time),max(time)
from table group by date
```

Comment: For future readers- this only works if there are exactly two values for each date.